# How to show multiple image in splash screen in Xamarin forms. Ios project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to show multiple images in splash screen. Now I am showing only one image. How can I show multiple images in Xamarin Forms.ios project. Please suggest any idea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look into creating a launch screen using the Interface Builder. You can put images, labels, basically every control on there if you want and set it as the launch screen in your `info.plist`. When creating a new project you will get a launch screen storyboard file in your iOS project.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/introduction/

Comment: Thanks Steven, I am using xamarin portable project. I am not find any .XIB file in my xamarin forms ios project.

Comment: It is most likely called LaunchScreen.storyboard. If its not in there you can add one by going to Add > New Item > iOS > Launch Screen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest. As you said we can add many launch screens in  IOS project but in INFO.PLIST we can select only one launch screen. Then how can we show multiple images in launch screen.

Comment: You can only have 1 launch screen. Like I said you can put all sorts of controls onto that launch screen by editing the `.storyboard` file. What you need to be doing is editing the `.storyboard` file and putting multiple Image controls on that.

Comment: I am very new to xamarin. Can you please send any sample code. I con't catch up exactly.

Comment: There is no code. The interface designer is a tool that lets you drag and drop all sorts of controls onto the storyboard. No code required.

Comment: I think you have to think that is need show multiple image in one splash screen but what the exact issue is show the splash screen images one after another not all images show in one time.

Comment: You can't have multiple splash screens so you will have to code logic into your splash screen that swaps out the images. You could also create a splashscreen with one image and have your first actual screen be a fake splashscreen that has this kind of behavior. I don't have any code lying around for either though.