# How to set gif image as a launch image in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to show multiple images one after another in splash screen, So I decided to set multiple images are converted in to gif image and add this gif image as a launch image. Can we set gif as launch image. Please suggest any idea to beat this requirement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show multiple image in splash screen in Xamarin forms. Ios project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013310/how-to-show-multiple-image-in-splash-screen-in-xamarin-forms-ios-project)

Comment: Here I want to set gif image to the launch image. In previous one show multiple images one after another. There is a difference between these two.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's guidelines it's not possible to use a GIF as/in a splash screen. Like I said in your other question, you can fake an animation by making your first view controller animated and setting it as the splash screen.

The `UIImageView` control in iOS has the ability to play a sequence of images one by one.